# Can't access profile page - Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, activity-tab

For some reason, I can't access my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu), when I try I get the following error:

> ## Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. **This is our fault**.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.stackoverflow.com.

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqVBM.png)

Oddly, I *can* view my profile (Larnu) if I browse unauthenticated or use my work account (as I didn't want to affiliate my work's Teams account with my "personal" account), and I can access the profile page for that account from my work account fine too. I don't have any problems viewing other people's profiles either, and I *can* view my profile on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu). If I try to view my [activities](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu?tab=topactivity) from a different account, or authentication, I get the error as well.

If I try to access someone else's activities, it is *very* slow for some users. Sometimes, after a while, I'll get the "Oops!" error, and other times it will eventually load. For example when I tried to view [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s?tab=topactivity)'s activities, it errored the first time, after awhile (I couldn't tell you how long, but 10's of seconds), and then loaded the second (again, after 10's of seconds). Accessing my activity from a "sock puppet" account, however, always appears to error immediately.

Comment: You got [the Staging Ground Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11548/staging-ground-beta?userid=2029983) badge. This somehow breaks any of the pages that show it in the Activity tab. That's Summary and Badges. I'm able to access the rest, like [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu?tab=answers) and I can see the badge is awarded in [All Actions > Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu?tab=activity&sort=badges). However, I don't know if you can access those.

Comment: It's a server-side caching issue, according to Yaakov.

Comment: No, I can't access [All Actions \> Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu?tab=activity&sort=badges) either, @VLAZ ; I get the same "Oops" error.

Comment: @Larnu yeah...thought might happen. The issue was reported in chat and the user who reported it also said they couldn't access any of the activity pages. But apparently another user can. Not sure why that happens.

Comment: either the issue is resolved or I am on of the lucky ones who can still see my profile

Comment: This broken to me, @WhatsThePoint, as is [your activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7147233/whatsthepoint?tab=topactivity)

Comment: Oddly enough I was experiencing the same issue. I was able to *navigate* to my profile page though and it loaded. Empty cache and hard reload in the main tab resolved it.

Comment: Looks like I can now also access my profile, though according to the SG Team the fix went out about [1 hour ago](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/questions/272#comment585_272).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** The fix for this issue has been deployed.

Sorry about this folks. When we added the Staging Ground badge, it got added in a way that we don't normally do it (programmatically through a dev route, and not through a sql-migration), and thus, it introduced a cache inconsistency. The new badge was refreshed in the local cache on only one of our servers, so users who are sent to any of the other servers are getting an error when loading some of the pages in their profiles.

A code change is waiting to be deployed to address this in the future (the actual deployment itself should take care of the cache, the code change will prevent a similar occurrence from causing an issue in the future). This should be up soon (this post will be updated when it is up). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Perhaps the error handling could be made more tolerant as a future-proofing measure? Why should "this user has a badge that I don't know how to render" make the entire page fail, rather than simply showing some kind of placeholder (or even just skipping it)?