# Profile Page taking a long time to load

Tags: bug, status-review, profile-page

I noticed, from Friday I think, that loading my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/thom-a) page is taking quite some time. When trying to view it, it can take up to 30 seconds to load. Once I've loaded it on a machine it loads up fine, for a while, so presumably caching is coming into effect afterwards. The caching appears to be client based though, as if I try to load my profile on a PC and then on a different device I still need to wait 20+ seconds to view my profile (therefore, hopefully, others will see the same behaviour).

I've noticed this behaviour on different devices, and at different locations (including at home, on mobile data, on a VPN, and at the office), and all 3 devices I've been using Firefox 115 on all devices (I think 115.0.1 on Friday morning and 115.0.2 Friday afternoon onwards).

I have, just now, tried loading with a different browser (Chromium and Edge) and the page loaded immediately, but unsure if that was due to caching caused from opening the page on Firefox beforehand and then using a different browser (I'll try again in an hour or so on a different browser to see if it appears to be Firefox specific).

[Animated gif demonstrating load time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3d1W.gif)

From further testing, it appears to only occur when I am authenticated (as myself), loading my profile unauthenticated doesn't have the issue. The issue, however, *does* occur on other browsers once authenticated. For example, loading on Edge (114.0.1823.82) took about 20 seconds, and then subsequent loads were immediate.

At the office the network monitor in Firefox shows that the [html took 18.56 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YCov.png), while everything else took ~0s. Of that, [18.48s was waiting time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC8Yf.png). I got similar a time (18.83s waiting) at home.

Martin Smith has [stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425609/profile-page-taking-a-long-time-to-load?noredirect=1#comment965929_425609) they are having the same problem. This suggests it could only be effecting users (on Stack Overflow) that have been very active (over the years). That users can't replicate it when viewing other's profiles also suggests that the matter is related to a process that only happens when viewing details of your own profile. It might be that a mod has similar behaviour when viewing a profile such as mine, as they are able to see more details, but only a mod would be able to confirm that.

---

As of 17 August 2023 this appears to be getting *worse* not better. Today my profile was taking almost [**30 seconds** to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAu7C.png). Bandwidth is not an issue (the office has just upgraded to a 1GB line).

Comment: I'm not experiencing this on FF 112.0.2. I just updated to FF 115.0.2, and I'm still not experiencing it (though it may be cached for me now).

Comment: Just tried on another device, and it only appears to happen on my profile when I'm authenticated. It loads immediately when I'm not authenticated.

Comment: It's loading immediately on Edge 114.0.1823.82 too. Same for Chrome 114.0.5735.199. Both logged in to my profile and with cache cleared.

Comment: You can disable cache by opening the developer tools to the network pane and checking "Disable Cache" before opening your profile to see whether its loading quickly due to the browsers cache or not.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat , it seems to not be local caching then, if caching is involved, as the page took 20-30 seconds to load, and then was immediate afterwards when disable caching was enabled.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that the problem is something that is run when I load my profile, as I can see more of my profile. A mod might get similar behaviour, as they can see more of my profile than a different user.

Comment: Does the network inspector show what in particular is taking so long to load?

Comment: I assume this is the "Network" tab, @vandench ? It shows that the [html took 18.56 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YCov.png), while everything else took ~0s. Of that, [18.48s was waiting time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC8Yf.png).

Comment: There's been examples of things being broken before because of profile stuff, @SecurityHound . For example [my profile was broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423468/2029983) earlier this year due to being given a badge.

Comment: I notice this as well. Seems to be caching related somewhere as it takes an age to load when I haven't accessed it for a while (a few hours maybe) but then is speedy when I refresh. I generally visit my user page quite regularly so I can revisit things I have commented on

Comment: @SecurityHound - RE: "Everyone’s profile is virtually identical" - maybe it is performing some activity that isn't scaling very well for users with large numbers of X - where X is maybe comments or answers

Comment: Fiddler shows that it seems to be the main HTML content for me too https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEpLR.png

Comment: Likewise to other user experiences, if I try to view your profile, @MartinSmith , it loads instantly. So it must be something that is loaded about the user's own profile that isn't show to other users. Unfortunately there's a wealth of stuff that could be. I wonder if it's a long running query against the database that's recently tanked in performance. *Quick, someone look at Query Store!*

Comment: Maybe relevant that we are both in the UK? Or that we are both in the Azure collective?

Comment: Possibly, @MartinSmith . I just tried on my phone using VPN with a server, and DNS, in New York and it still took about 20~seconds to load.

Comment: I've left the Azure Collective and will see if that solves it for me

Comment: No apparent difference. I still just encountered a ~20 second loading time again

Comment: FWIW, @MartinSmith , I've contacted [so] via the Contact Us page. I've mentioned you're having the same issue. If something is found and the staff aren't forthcoming here, I'll share anything I get in response as a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: @ThomA - Thanks. I imagine these long requests should be very easy for them to see in the logs!

Comment: With the frequency I visit my own profile page, I hope so!

Comment: Having the same issue, with my own SO profile page.

Comment: Any movement on this? The issue is getting worse.

Comment: @V2Blast How is the review going? This issue still exists

Comment: I have noticed, as well, that the page tends to take longer to load more often, and the average load time is over 19 seconds now (was 18).

Comment: Might be fixed? Any way I just visited my profile and don't think I visited it that recently and it seemed to load in a normal time. Will try again in a few hours

Comment: Still taking awhile for me, @MartinSmith .

Comment: Hmm, fingers crossed but seems fixed for me

Comment: Well, it's *faster* today at least. 8-9 seconds instead of 18-19. Still not ideal, but better™.

Comment: Strange - mine is down to much less than that. Long may it continue

Comment: Though I have noticed that the inbox is sometimes taking a long time to load today. Maybe the issue is with the "Responses" tab on the profile which would explain why it doesn't appear when viewing other people's

Comment: Doesn't appear to be related to responses, @MartinSmith  (I just cleared mine). I *do* wonder if it's to do with flags, as there would have been a significant number of outstanding flags until recently, and I have quite a few that have been outstanding for some time. Wonder if the volume I have outstanding combined with the total volume outstanding is a bottlenecked query; it would explain why after the strike it has started to get better and why it started only *after* the strike had been ongoing for awhile. But this is completely conjecture.

Comment: As a mod, I've certainly seen the profile page take a while to load even on other users.  But our view of the profile page is slightly different than normal users' view, so that might not be universal.

Comment: Any news on this @V2blast ? It's still taking some time for my profile to load.

Comment: Issue returned for me yesterday after going away for two weeks :-(

Comment: I'll ping the devs to follow up on this.

Comment: No news, I assume, @V2Blast ? I can confirm this is *still* ongoing.

Comment: @ThomA - It seems like it may be fixed for me again. Are you still seeing it?

Comment: Yeah, mine is actually loading in an acceptable time now as well, @MartinSmith . Would be nice have had some kind of update, and/or a reason of why the (huge) degradation on performance.

Comment: Looks like it's back for me, @MartinSmith , and possibly worse than last time.

Comment: Same for me.  @V2Blast how come no news on this?

Comment: @V2Blast this problem is becoming [progressively worse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFZnW.png); are the seriously *no* updates on this..?

Comment: Looks like it's back again... No updates still @V2Blast ?

Comment: Also it appears to be the most severe it's been; my profile took **30.14** *seconds* to load just now. A second load, after it's cached, took 253ms (so almost *120 times* faster).

Comment: @ThomA - Unfortunately V2Blast was in the round of redundancies :-(. I noticed it had suddenly got worse too. Anecdotally often it seems to happen on Sundays that this problem reappears.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that V2Blast had lost their [Staff] badge, @MartinSmith ; good spot. I agree, it does seem to start on a Sunday as I did notice degraded performance yesterday. Suspect I'll have to go to the Contact Us page again. Though I have the opinion that [so] just *don't care*; they're more interested in ramming AI and Collectives down our throats...

Comment: Forgot to mention, I did reach out to SO, @MartinSmith . I basically got told that investigation is slow due to staff-shortages, something that I can only find irony in, considering that SO only has itself to blame for these shortages after they made all the recent redundancies and moved developers onto features no one wants... I suspect that this "feature" is here to staff until it impacts someone who works at the business, cares, and is in a position to solve it...

Comment: Seems like the issue is back again. It was gone for the best part of 2, maybe 3, months.